# Router not opening website anymore

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I've been accessing a particular website fine via my router and suddenly, it doesn't open anymore. I've tried using other devices connected to my network but that doesn't work. Though, when I connect to another network or my 4G, the website opens.

I had same issue a few weeks back with the same website and the same router but somehow, it started working via my network a few days ago and now it has stopped.

These are what I've tried below:

```
 1. ipconfig/flushdns
 2. netsh winsock reset catalog
 3. netsh int ip reset reset.log
 4. changed dns to Google's [8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4]
 5. restart pc and router
```

This is the output of my tracert:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJwba.png)

Comment: Have you tried a free vpn service to see if it is your ISP blocking the site?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Hi @DavidPostill, I get the error that the site could not be reached. Apologies for the late reply, I haven't been able to log in.

Comment: @ChrisRogers I haven't tried that but I'm sure that isn't the case because I was able to access the site two days ago and I've tried another router by my ISP and it accessed the site.

Comment: Please [edit] and include the output from `tracert` (or `traceroute` depending on your OS) for the site in question.

Comment: @DavidPostill, I've posted an image of the tacert. Also, I just tried using a VPN like you said via my mobile and it was able to access the website but when I went off the VPN, I couldn't access the site. I find this strange because another router by the same ISP can access the website. Do I speak to my ISP about this?

Comment: Try Flush routing table (reboot required) `route /f`

Comment: @DavidPostill I tried that but it still doesn't access the website.

Answer (score 0):

You said in the comments that using a VPN allows you access to the website which sounds to me that either your ISP is blocking access to the site or the website is blocking you due to where you are in the world as VPNs can mask your location. (see https://tenta.com/blog/post/2016/10/types-of-sites-you-can-access-with-a-vpn)

You also said that you are able to access the site via another network or 4G mobile when blocked on the router. This rules out locality (where you are in the world) so that leaves your ISP.

If there should be no restrictions on accessing the website, I would contact your ISP for them to look into it.